# Setting contentType on AudioStreamer

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I use the AudioPlayer to stream both mp3 and AAC Shoutcast streams on iOS, and in the main it works just fine. However to get AAC to work with a URL that does not end in .aac I had to hack the AudioStreamerCUR.m Objective-C code. I am not an Objective-C programmer and this was done very much on a trial and error basis. As there are number of url schemes used by Shoutcast and Icecast, my hacks are messy and it would be a lot easier to simply send the content-type along with the url like this:

```
var player = Titanium.Media.createAudioPlayer({ 
allowsAirPlay: true,
url: myURL,
contentType: "aac"
})
```

But I can't work out how to get a new property into the AudioPlayer proxy and then across to the actual AudioStreamerCUR.m - it seems some black magic is required. I wonder if there are any magicians who could point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a property currently not exposed though the Titanium AudioPlayer API.

You might want to do a Feature Request [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). Check if it has already been requested before you create a new ticket. Refer to this question and also link back to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Hello Fokke - I did add a feature request for this on the end of TIMOB-3375, but it's an old ticket that has been open since 2011, and although is marked as High Priority has never been fully resolved. Which doesn't fill me with much confidence. I don't think Appcelerator take playing audio very seriously. In the meantime I have done some naive hacks to AudioStreamerCUR to push through some kind of contentType hint.

Comment: I've asked for the ticket to be reopened. I see it probably stranded because someone linked his fork and was asked to do a PR but he never did: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-3375